# a line with glued spheres (balls)

Tags: general-topology

I am totally ignorant about topology, tried to google but didn't find answers for the following questions:

1. Is there something (nomenclature, basic properties) for an object which is a line to each point of which a 3d ball is attached (glued?). I.e., at every point of a line I could choose a point from a surface and interior of a sphere.
2. Can I be more specific and demand a cube instead of the ball (eventhough from the point of topology they are perhaps identical objects).

Could you please direct me to a relevant literature?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. (The two 'is's in your first question are throwing me off.)

Comment: I concur with the above comment. The wording for the first question is unclear.

Comment: It might also help if you tell us why at all you are interested in such an object for example are you trying to construct covering spaces ?

Comment: Thank you,  @Mr.Gandalf Sauron
 for suggesting this. The story is a bit specific and long but I'll try to condense it. Namely, I am dealing with a class of operators (quantum  maps) which are parametrized by parameter $d$ (degree of deviation from the detailed balance condition). Each map is additionally specified by its asymptotic state (density operator). States form a topological sphere  (surface plus interior), so for every value of $d \in [0,1]$ I can choose one of the  states as the asymptotic state and design the corresponding quantum map.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is $\mathbb{R}\times D^3$ or $[0,1]\times D^3$, depending on whether you want your *line* to be compact. And yes, you can basically demand anything you want. To replace the ball with a cube, just replace the $D^3$ above by $[0,1]^3$.

Comment: Thank you, @CeyhunElmaci. Are such "beads"  known & used in some fields?

Comment: They are called "fiber bundles" and they are a major concern of differential geometry and differential topology. A fiber bundle consists of a manifold, the "base space" ($\Bbb R$ here), and second manifold, the "fibration" ($\Bbb R\times D^3$ here), and a "projection map" $\pi$ from the fibration onto the base space (here, the projection $\Bbb R\times D^3 \to \Bbb R : (t, p) \mapsto t$), with the requirement that the inverse image of each point in the base space should be homeomorphic or diffeomorphic to some model "fiber" (here $D^3$). This fiber bundle is "trivial" since it is a product.

Comment: Thank you, $Paul! This is exactly what I was needed.